# difference between HTML5 and native iOS aps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

Could somebody list some things that you can do using native iPhone/iPad development but you can't using HTML5? I want to understand for what kind of apps is HTML5 usefull. I like it because it is an open technology which you can reuse to target other mobiles like android. I remember Steve Jobs said HTML5 is the future but I want to understand hat are it's limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference I guess is that with an HTML5 app you don't have access to the native APIs and access to onboard devices (like the accelerometer, camera, etc.).

If you use something like [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) though you can have the best of both worlds.

Comment: It isn't necessarily the best of both worlds. For example, until iOS5, JavaScript running in Phonegap is dramatically slower than JavaScript running in Safari (http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/apple-phonegap-html5-nitro).

Comment: @ceejayoz: You caught me right in the middle of adding that to the answer, I shan't bother now :-)